# how to convert xlm file below to excel with nodes as column names and its values as rows in c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC><REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME><STATICVARIABLES><SVCURRENTCOMPANY>MSIT</SVCURRENTCOMPANY></STATICVARIABLES></REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE>
    <Entry_x0020_NO.>125</Entry_x0020_NO.>
    <DATE>12</DATE>
    <GUID>1258</GUID>
    <NARRATION>1542</NARRATION>
    <VOTURETYPENAME>456</VOTURETYPENAME>
    <NAME>achuth</NAME>
    <AMOUNT>250</AMOUNT>
  </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

the above XML is taken as input and convert to excel as below

```
Entry No.   date  guid   narration   voucher   name   amount  
125         12     1258     1542      456      achuth  250
```

the code for me throws error null reference as below[image]

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494967/how-to-convert-xml-to-excel-file-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast `XElement` instance to `string` instead of accessing its `Value` property to avoid such exception in the case where the target element is not found within a parent element :

```
......
new YourClass()
{
    YourClassProperty = (string)s.Element("Your_element_that_may_not_exists"),
    ......
}
......
```

Comment: i dint get u sorry

Comment: @achuthhadnoor It is likely that one of your `s.Element()` part returns `null`, and trying to access `Value` property of a `null` should trigger the [null reference exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). So instead of doing `s.Element(...).Value`, try using the the above suggested pattern `(string)s.Element(...)`