# Cutting a String before a special character everytime in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have strings that all have different lengths.
e.g.

```
str1 = "This is new job ----First Message----- This is reopened ";
str2 = "Start Process ----First Message----- Is this process closed? <br/> no ----First Message-----";
```

Now these string shall always have the `"----First Message-----"` in it.
What I need is to trim or split the string in such a way that I only get the part left of the FIRST TIME the `"----First Message-----"` occurs.

So in case of `str1` result should be "This is new job "
For `str2` it should be `"Start Process "`

How can this be done in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Substring - everything before certain char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857513/get-substring-everything-before-certain-char)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string stringStart = str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf("----First Message-----"));
```

Comment: This returns the string you want so make sure to capture it in a variable if you want to use it later, etc.  It doesn't modify str1's contents.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: @JoshP thanks for pointing that out; I've edited the answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
String result = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('---FirstMessage-----'));
```

actually, for teaching purposes...

```
private String GetTextUpToFirstMessage( String input ){
    const string token = "---FirstMessage-----";
    return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(token));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for REGULAR EXPRESSIONS!!!!

try the following code.  don't forget to include the `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` statement at the top.

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(.*)----FirstMessage----$");
    string myString = regex.Match(str1).Value;
```

Comment: can you check this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131758/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings

Comment: Now you have two problems.... the $ at the end will ensure that you don't get a match with the data in the question.