# How to Split a String into an Array Of Strings?

Tags: c#, string, split, xps

Actually i am reading an xps.file in to my Program. My xps file should be like this
[image]

I paste the following code

```
List<string> lData = new List<string>();
        using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(fileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            FixedDocumentSequence docSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            Dictionary<string, string> docPageText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < docSeq.DocumentPaginator.PageCount; pageNum++)
            {
                DocumentPage docPage = docSeq.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(pageNum);
                foreach (System.Windows.UIElement uie in ((FixedPage)docPage.Visual).Children)
                {
                    if (uie is System.Windows.Documents.Glyphs)
                    {
                        lData.Add(((System.Windows.Documents.Glyphs)uie).UnicodeString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

By using the above code i am getting the List of elements. Based on that i am getting a String separated with **Space**

```
            foreach (string elmnt in lData)
        {
            strText += elmnt + " ";
        }
```

From this string i want to split it. String should be like this

```
LD1089546 LD1089546 LD1089546 ABDLys2HO+ ScreenLysP - LD1089547 LD1089547 LD1089547 ScreenLysP - LD1089548 LD1089548 LD1089548 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ 
LD1089549 LD1089549 LD1089549 ABDLys2HO+ ScreenLysP - LD1094450 LD1094450 LD1094450 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ LD1094451 LD1094451 LD1094451 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094452 LD1094452 LD1094452 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ LD1094453 LD1094453 LD1094453 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ LD1094454 LD1094454 LD1094454 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094455 LD1094455 LD1094455 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ LD1094456 LD1094456 LD1094456 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HAB+ LD1094457 LD1094457 LD1094457 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ 
LD1094458 LD1094458 LD1094458 ABDLys2HAB+ ScreenLysP - LD1094461 LD1094461 LD1094461 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ LD1094463 LD1094463 LD1094463 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HXX 
LD1094464 LD1094464 LD1094464 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ LD1094465 LD1094465 LD1094465 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ LD1094466 LD1094466 LD1094466 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+
```

i want result Array should be Like this

```
LD1089546 LD1089546 LD1089546 ABDLys2HO+ ScreenLysP - 
LD1089547 LD1089547 LD1089547 ScreenLysP - 
LD1089548 LD1089548 LD1089548 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ 
LD1089549 LD1089549 LD1089549 ABDLys2HO+ ScreenLysP - 
LD1094450 LD1094450 LD1094450 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094451 LD1094451 LD1094451 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094452 LD1094452 LD1094452 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ 
LD1094453 LD1094453 LD1094453 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ 
LD1094454 LD1094454 LD1094454 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094455 LD1094455 LD1094455 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HA+ 
LD1094456 LD1094456 LD1094456 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HAB+ 
LD1094457 LD1094457 LD1094457 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HO+ 
LD1094458 LD1094458 LD1094458 ABDLys2HAB+ ScreenLysP - 
LD1094461 LD1094461 LD1094461 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HB+ 
LD1094463 LD1094463 LD1094463 ScreenLysP - ABDLys2HXX
```

Comment: So you want the result to be a 5 x 15 array?

Comment: second row has only four elements

Comment: Instead of `strText += elmnt + " ";` You could use `string.Join(separator, list);`

Comment: Yes @Richard i want like that

Comment: I think we need some more information on what the criteria is for a new row in your expected array.

Comment: Yes i am excepting an Array, after getting i have some other process to do. i want to split the Resulted Array based on space and insert into datagridview

Comment: XPS is really not set up for this sort of data interchange - you should really consider whether there is any other way to get at the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at these DotNetPearls examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: I don't get it johngrinder

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to split your text. Here is some interesting links :

- You can start with this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719739%28VS.110%29.aspx
- Quick reference langage : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- A cool tool to test online your RegEx : http://regexhero.net/tester/

Hope this helps.