# search a character from string and store all data into a variable before that char

Tags: c#

I have a string variable which stores the values of an URL like

```
"http://abc/abc_UAT/CustomerDetail.aspx?r=1".
```

I just need to search the character `?` and need to store all character before '?' into another string variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Substring - everything before certain char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857513/get-substring-everything-before-certain-char)

Comment: The given duplicate is the first result by searching for "c# string before char". Please do your own research and include it in your question if still need help

Comment: You might consider using the Uri class to parse a URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will give you the answer even if this post is a duplicate.

You can use the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

e.g. :

```
var before = "http://abc/abc_UAT/CustomerDetail.aspx?r=1";
var wantedString = before.Split('?')[0];
```

Comment: "I will give you the answer even if this post is a duplicate." - Please don't, while it may be tempting to get a quick reputation gain, its not great for the site in the long term since it can make it harder for people to search for material. (Plus it encourages people to post more bad questions)

Comment: There isn't anything stopping you doing this, its just mine and a few others opinion of course...

Comment: Actually for beginners it's really tough to find out the actual result by searching in site. I tried to do with Substring and indexOf like ---------

string set1 = "http://abc/abc_UAT/CustomerDetail.aspx?r=1";
var res = set1.Substring(set1.IndexOf('?'));

------- but the result was "?r=1".

Comment: Split function solves my problem easily. Thank you so much.