# remove all characters after X character

Tags: c#

Please check variable "mystr" value where a "-" sign between two part of numbers. I want to find "-" then remove all character after that then I want find same "-" and remove all Character from first to till that. I know it's simple but not getting exact solution on c# due to I am new.

```
public void test()
    {
        string mystr = "1.30-50.50";

        //first output I want is-  "1.30" 
        //second output I want is-  "50.50" 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Substring - everything before certain char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857513/get-substring-everything-before-certain-char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var mystr = "1.30-50.50";
var result = mystr.Split('-');
var a = result[0]; //"1.30" 
var b = result[1]; //"50.50"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
string mystr = "1.30-50.50";
int indexOfDash = mystr.IndexOf('-');
string firsResult = mystr.Substring(0, indexOfDash);
string secondResult = mystr.Substring(indexOfDash + 1, mystr.Length - indexOfDash - 1);
```